# Get initial copy of untracked files when pulling, forking

Tags: git, gitignore

I am new to git and I couldn't phrase it correctly when searching, so I could not find any relevant info about this. So basically, my problem is:

I have a git repo that has some config files and other php files. I dont want the config files to be tracked. But if someone pull or forks, or clones from that repo, I want them to still get a initial copy of the file, so they can put their config on it.

So,what is the best way to do it? So that git only tracks the initial copy, and others can pull initial of the untracked and latest of the tracked ones.

Answer (score 1):

Don't track your config file (or in other words, list you config file in `.gitignore` file)
Instead, create a config "example" - (if your config's file name is `config.ini`, you'll usually have it called `config.example.ini` - and add this file to your git REPO - this way, the users can know the structure of the config file, but you wan't expose any secret data

Comment: This is exactly the way laravel does it with active untracked `.env` and tracked `example.env`